# Composer PHP 7.2 only

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7

Composer is only working via PHP 7.2, if I swap to PHP 7.1 it has no output when used.

---

**Composer w/ PHP 7.2 - Working**

[image]

**Composer w/ PHP 7.1 - Not Working**

[image]

---

Done alot of research and cannot find any answers as to why this would happen. I want to install Magento 2.x release but it doesn't support PHP 7.2

This is on Shared Linux Hosting with Crazy Domains. Using SSH without root access.

Comment: Does it have execute permissions? (chmod +x /path/to/composer)
Is there anything in the binary at all? (cat path/to/composer)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RGSSCgk
I've removed cache & uninstalled previous Magento 2.3 BETA which I used composer to install.

Comment: It may be throwing errors which could be suppressed by the php cli config, maybe you could try turning on error reporting in the bin itself? There is also a check you can execute to see if your environment can run composer properly `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check`

Comment: PHP 7.1 - All settings correct for using Composer
PHP 7.2 - All settings correct for using Composer

 How do I turn on error reporting as I do not have access to /opt/alt/php7.x/etc
as thats what php --ini is showing. There is a php.ini file in the main directory though.
https://imgur.com/a/fesyw1p